# How to get formData from Angular-Payments

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ngmodel

I am using [Angular-Payments](https://github.com/laurihy/angular-payments) that intercepts the form data and submits it to Stripe. This works well, however, I'm not sure how to access form data after its sent to stripe. For example, my form has quantity field which I would like to get access to but I don't know how to...

Here is what I'm doing HTML

```
<form stripe-form="handleStripe" role="form" ng-if="authenticated" name="takeMoneyForm" ng-submit="takeMoney(takeMoneyForm, model)">
      <input type="text" name="card_number" ng-model="number" payments-validate="card" payments-format="card" payments-type-model="type" ng-class="takeMoneyForm.number.$card.type">
       <input type="text"  name="card_cvc" ng-model="cvc" payments-validate="cvc" payments-format="cvc" payments-type-model="type">
      <input type="text" nam="card_expiry" ng-model="expiry" payments-validate="expiry" payments-format="expiry">
      <input type="text" ng-model="quantity"/>
      <button class='form-control  submit-button btn btn-majoo' type='submit'>Pay »</button>
</form>
```

JS

```
  $scope.takeMoney = function(formData, model){
    $scope.handleStripe = function(status, response){
      if(response.error) {
        // there was an error. Fix it.
        alert("Error happened")
      } else {
        var dataModel = {
          email: model.email,
          profile: {
            stripe_token: response.id,
            stripe_id: model.profile.stripe_id
            //here I would like to get access to the quantity from the form
          }
        }
        djangoAuth.takeMoney(dataModel)
        $scope.complete = true;
      }
    }
  }
```

I feel like this should be simple but I'm very new to Angular and can't seem to figure this out.

Answer (score 0):

since youre using `ng-model` the values of those fields should be on that form's scope(as in `scope.number`)
If they are not accessible it could be one of two things:

1) Angular Payments clears the ng-model following submit

2) you are trying to access it from a different scope.